# Calling MySQL stored procedure with Twisted adbapi

Tags: mysql, twisted, mysql-python

I'm trying to call a MySQL stored procedure from Twisted adbapi using the MySQLdb interface but cannot get it to work. I saw that there is a special way to call stored procedure in MySQLdb (callproc), so I was wondering if there was a special way to call it from the adbapi.

My stored procedure takes two fields `A_PROCEDURE(field1 VARCHAR(20), field2 VARCHAR(25))` and I'm attempting to call it in my program in the way most obvious to me: `dbpool.runOperation("CALL A_PROCEDURE(%s,%s)", arg1, arg2)`. This attempt called the errback. The procedure works fine if I just test it from my terminal connection to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `runInteraction` to do arbitrary database or adapter specific things like this:

```
def aProcedure(cursor, arg1, arg2):
    cursor.execute("CALL A_PROCEDURE(%s, %s)", (arg1, arg2))
    return cursor.fetchall()

d = dbpool.runInteraction(aProcedure, arg1, arg2)
...
```